# Enabling CDC on a table in a DDL Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, cdc

I am attempting to disable\enable CDC in a DDL trigger like so:

```
ALTER TRIGGER trgTableAlter
ON DATABASE
FOR 
    ALTER_TABLE 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @EventData XML = EVENTDATA(), @schemaname varchar(255) = '', @tablename nvarchar(255), @tableid bigint = NULL

    SELECT @tablename = @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]',  'NVARCHAR(255)')

    --get schema for table don't assume dbo
    SELECT @schemaname = TABLE_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tablename

    SET @tableid = NULL;
    SET @tableid = object_id(@schemaname + '.' + @tablename)

    --verify table has cdc enabled. if so then disable\enable
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE object_id = @tableid AND is_tracked_by_cdc = 1)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @old_capture_instance sysname,  @indexname varchar(255), @rolename varchar(255)

        SELECT @old_capture_instance = capture_instance, 
        @indexname = index_name, @rolename = role_name 
        FROM cdc.change_tables WHERE source_object_id = @tableid

        BEGIN
            EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_table
                @source_schema = @schemaname, 
                @source_name = @tablename, 
                @capture_instance = @old_capture_instance;
        END

        BEGIN
            EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
                @source_schema = @schemaname,
                @source_name = @tablename,
                @role_name = @rolename,
                @index_name = @indexname,
                @supports_net_changes = 1, 
                @capture_instance = 'Test1'
        END
        

    END
END
```

After setting up the trigger and attempt to alter a CDC enabled table I get the following error

```
Msg 22832, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sys.sp_cdc_enable_table_internal, Line 673 [Batch Start Line 10]
Could not update the metadata that indicates table [dbo].[bHQUM] is enabled for Change Data Capture. The failure occurred when executing the command 'insert into [cdc].[index_columns]'. The error returned was 3930: 'The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.'. Use the action and error to determine the cause of the failure and resubmit the request.
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 2, Line 11
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

Is it simply not possible to enable and disable CDC in a DDL trigger? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: In the interest of debugging, I'd interleave calls to `xact_state()` before/after your calls to the CDC procs and print it out. The error message seems to indicate that something has made the transaction uncommittable but it's not clear whether that's happening *before* or *within* the call to `sp_cdc_enable_table`.

Comment: Unrelated, a given table can have two capture instances on it in order to facilitate bridging schema changes. The workflow is typically "make table change", "add new capture instance", "get all data from old instance up to LSN of new instance", "cut over to use new instance", "drop old instance".

Comment: I originally had the enable first, but I switched it around while debugging. Same error though.  I will try your debugging suggestions. Thanks!